# How to create and search in a language dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, ios6

I'm working on an Xcode project.

I need to add a dictionary of words, like English dictionary for example. Then, when required, I need to find some words in it.

I have been thinking about creating an array from a file to store all the words, then sort it in some way I don't know and at last do a binary search or something like this to find the word I'm looking for.

- Do you think is a good idea?
- Do you have any clue to sort the array?
- Is binary search a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use a database (e.g. SQL-based), or CoreData to store it. That is unless you require the words to be entirely in the memory, which would be the case if you often listed all of them. But even then it can be solved by lazy-loading.

Comment: CoreData is probably the easiest and can sync with iCloud almost with zero effort - there are many tutorials on the web for this though, explaining it probably better than I would.